# Converting a darknet model to a tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, yolo, darknet

I converted a pytorch(.pt) model  to a darknet model (.weights)
then when I tried to convert the darknet mode to tensorflow model (.tf) I got this error

```
assert len(wf.read()) == 0, 'failed to read all data'

AssertionError: failed to read all data
```

Comment: https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow/issues/527, Try referring this discussion

Comment: i am using this repo (https://github.com/zzh8829/yolov3-tf2) and i think  that the problem occure because i am using yolov3-spp.weights and in the repo there is only yolov3.weights and yolov3-tiny.weights

Comment: We've modified the zzh8829 script for the yolov4-spp at https://github.com/sicara/tf2-yolov4 if it helps